# ConnectionString Exception In Oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I want to insert some data into an Oracle database through a C# application.

I keep getting an exception which looks like this : "The ConnectionString has not been properly initialized".
The code for inserting is bellow:

try
            {

```
                conn.openConnection();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn.Connection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

               String sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO ComandaDVD (Id_Comanda,Id_Format,Data_Comanda,Id_TipPlata,Pret) VALUES (" +
                    "'" + txt_idComanda.Text + "', " +
                    "'" + txtFormat.Text + "', " +
                    "to_date('" + txtData.Text + "', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), " +
                    "'" + txtIdTipPlata.Text + "', " +
                    "'" + txtPret.Text + "')";

                cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Comanda cu id_comanda[" + txt_idComanda.Text + "]a fost primita!");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Eroare");
                }

                conn.closeConnection();            
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exceptie" + ex.Message);
        }         
    }
```

I also made a personalized class to ease the connection handling:
 class Conexiune_DB
    {

```
    private OracleConnection conn;
    private static string CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=80.96.123.131/ora09;User Id=hr;Password=oracletest;";

    public Conexiune_DB() { conn = new OracleConnection(CONNECTION_STRING); }

    public void openConnection() { conn.Open(); } 

    public void closeConnection() { conn.Dispose(); } 

    public OracleConnection Connection
    {
        get { return conn; }     
    }

}
```

The exception appears to be because of 'conn.Open' in that class. Which is weird, because i made some insertions before, and i didn't have any problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is plenty of info on that error in the web. Try to look around and you'll most probably find where you're wrong.

Comment: You should always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure this happens because you're opening your connection with `conn.openConnection();` before you've even set a ConnectionString to it. So instead you should first set the ConnectionString to your `conn` before opening it. I'm not sure which connectionstring you'd like to use in this moment, but if it's the same, then just put `conn.Conexiune_DB();` above `conn.openConnection();`

Comment: i figured it out after all. i had to get rid of the connection class,and instantiante a OracleConnection object in each function.

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);

 which i guess is kinda the same thing D. Petrox said. thank you, i appreciate your help.